# Freemarker templates: How split small string in size of 34 using freemarker

Tags: string, templates, freemarker

I would like to split a small/long string in size of 34 in freemarker template.

How could this be done with freemarker instruments?

Example:
String  - `"1234567890A234567890B234567890C234567890D234567890E234567890F234567890G234567890H234567890I234567890J234567890K234567890L234567890M234567890"`

Range size - 34

Result should look like this
`1234567890A234567890B234567890C234 567890D234567890E234567890F2345678 90G234567890H234567890I234567890J2 34567890K234567890L234567890M23456`

Expecting
`1234567890A234567890B234567890C234 567890D234567890E234567890F2345678 90G234567890H234567890I234567890J2 34567890K234567890L234567890M23456`

Example 2:
String  - `"1234567890A234567890"`

Range size - 34

Result should look like this
`1234567890A234567890`

Expecting
`1234567890A234567890`

When the string length is less eg str = '1234567890A234567890' and i want to make a chunk of size 34 then in the output i want --- 1234567890A234567890 also there should be only 4 chunks of 34. If the string size is more than after getting 4 chucks of the defined length it should truncate the remaining string data.

Comment: I want the string to be truncated  strictlty after 136(i.e 4 chuncks of 34) index position.this query is taking data till the last index position of the string

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in function which can do this for you. I will come down to do some counting and taking substrings based on the token size (34 in your case).

This will work if you just want to output something and you are not able to facilitate a Java function, and only can use FreeMarker:

```
<#assign longStr = "1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz">
<#assign tokenSize = 34>
<#assign tokenCount = (longStr?length / tokenSize)?ceiling>

<#list 0..<tokenCount as index>
<#assign tokenStart = index * tokenSize>
<#assign tokenEnd = (tokenStart + tokenSize > longStr?length)?then(longStr?length, tokenStart + tokenSize)>
${longStr[tokenStart..<tokenEnd]}
</#list>
```

However if you are able to do this in Java, it's much better in my opinion, as it will keep your FreeMarker template much cleaner.

Used built-ins:

- https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html#ref_builtin_length
- https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_number.html#ref_builtin_rounding
- https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_boolean.html#ref_builtin_then

Used directives:

- https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_directive_list.html

Used expressions:

- https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_stringop_slice